# How to draw polylines from Google Directions Api

Tags: android, google-maps, google-directions-api

I'm trying to draw a [polyline](/questions/tagged/polyline) from what the Google Directions Api returns, the api has this field, overview_polyline, I'm assuming that this field contains the entire polyline so I was thinking why not draw the polyline from there, this is what I have in my JSON, from Google:

```
{
     geocoded_waypoints: [
        {},
        {}
     ],
     routes: [
        {
           bounds: {},
           copyrights: "Dados do mapa ©2017 Google, Inst. Geogr. Nacional",
           legs: [],
           overview_polyline: {
               points: "cxwnFtdct@dAQlAf@fAf@|Aq@l@]pCcFhCjA|LfJlAT~@IpDi@jAb@f@HXi@t@kBhBeBx@Qz@z@dClHzFpW`H|RvTpj@`AxAdBdAnAXhB?fBk@rAcAnG_HhCgAjAKrATbA`Al@lBHnAc@rFgBhIkCxMBfIlBvHnBtCnB|AnEdCrJxFj@fB@h@OhAgCtHGfCl@jAlA\jE]tDBzBb@tLxFtK~E`d@hShIzEtDhDxDrEfDpFlFjNvDtRdDjThF`TzH`QhEhG|EvFhL`JpJtE|LpEdOpFjOzGlPfJlHzE~NjLfQvPfP|RtHrKxDjGfI|NdHbOvGjPfCbHpCtIvJh_@vG|[|CtNvFvSvE~MfI|QzLbTfNxQbKlKrRzP|NnNvNlQjIzMnLfV`T|h@nDbHhIdMxFjH~JrMnEfHzIrQfHvOtEjI|MnQfNzP`FzI~EnLrKp[nDlHvErHzL~MbRbM`EjCjFxEtRnX|D~EjIhI~WrRxGlGdFnG`JjNxHzKfTxVfKfRfMbRlErHtBlFxIjYvHnPpBtFxF~WpCjHjGhJfDzClF~CnDlArDl@pC\vHXvX[lOaB|GcBdFqBxQwJbDmAxE_ApJ_@jEXtItBrQ~EbQbDlUfBpMfA|IxCbF`DhGlGnJjKtJrF`SpFbRnDdUxAbGrAlEjBnFpDtNnMfGlE~[lTbRdQjTpUxH`GjHfEnGlC`O|DrUxEnEzAfFrBnSpIjPnDxSlAf\lAl~@hDzRrAjOpBvKrBrQtEv^pM``@rPrR|JxSdMlGnGfGtH~HxFdFlBtGfApGp@bG|AnHxD|FzFrH`L~FvH|HrFrFtBtFjA~Mt@pHR|FhA`IfDpEbDzFxGrHrKhEtErF`EnS`MzMvItSdUfF~DtE~B|SrInEnBzDtCxN`QpQfVtQ~Yjn@~fAnK`RvLlRzEjF|GlFrc@vUfRjKfIvGxDhEjIxKdN~T`L~MrFvE~LhIlp@fb@xCtBzFtFbEzFbDrGhH`TfF|JnGfHzEdD|UdIpTdHtKtFj]nUrEzC~[pTfLfG|EbB~KfCnTvDpmAxSzs@~LhOfDzOdFfOxGdY`O`k@zYnVzMlK|HrFjFbXj[rCbCvDfB|FfBbD^xRBlb@nBrIdArJvDfD|B|FzFvFzHnCbIDrCk@dA_A_@q@mHz@sAvAJ^f@r@n@x@UR_@fBGjET`S~@ro@pCpXpAfFp@dEhCnGtE@HXl@n@H^W|ASpShAbZxAtPp@~SjAzGZKdDStBd@x@dC@nEVz@HtAp@b@\OZ|AbBxDnFJf@"
           },
           summary: "A1",
           warnings: [ ],
           waypoint_order: [ ]
        }
     ],
     status: "OK"
 }
```

How do I draw with that value?

Answer (score 1):

This help me,you can use it..
Firstly create a google server key from google developer account

```
GoogleDirection.withServerKey(getResources().getString(R.string.SERVER_KEY))
                        .from(SourceLatlng)
                        .to(DestinationLatlng)
                        .execute(new DirectionCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDirectionSuccess(Direction direction, String message) {
                                if (direction.isOK()) {
                                    routeSucess2(direction, message,SourceLatlng,DestinationLatlng);
                                } else {
                                    //selectedRawLine = ERROR;
                                }

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onDirectionFailure(Throwable t) {
                                t.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        });
```

then draw a route using google direction

```
 private void routeSucess2(Direction direction, String message,LatLng sourceLatlng,LatLng DestinationLng) {

        for (Route route : direction.getRouteList()) {
            PolylineOptions polyoptions = new PolylineOptions();
            polyoptions.color(getResources().getColor(R.color.primary__dark));
            polyoptions.width(5);
            polyoptions.addAll(route.getOverviewPolyline().getPointList());
            poly = googleMap.addPolyline(polyoptions);
            poly.setClickable(true);

        }
        LatLngBounds.Builder latLngBuilder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
        if(sourceLatlng!=null)
        latLngBuilder.include(sourceLatlng);
        if(DestinationLng!=null)
        latLngBuilder.include(DestinationLng);

        try {
            LatLngBounds bounds = latLngBuilder.build();
            CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds,
                    UiHelper.dpToPixel(getActivity(), 135));
            googleMap.animateCamera(cu);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

This would help you.

Answer (score 0):

@alb First you should parse lat,long from JSON. You can see this link:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/

Then you have to get lat, long values & put them in List<>.

After that you can use below code for draw polyline on map:

```
PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions().width(5).color(Color.BLUE).geodesic(true);
for (int z = 0; z < list.size(); z++) {
    LatLng point = list.get(z);
    options.add(point);
}
line = myMap.addPolyline(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

I already have replied on similar question on below link

[How to buffer a polyline in Android or draw a polygon around a polyline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39454857/how-to-buffer-a-polyline-in-android-or-draw-a-polygon-around-a-polyline/42664925#42664925)

It will resolve your Issue probably